# Gradle build configured signatory

Tags: java, gradle, push-notification, pem, web-push

I'm looking at the [webpush-java](https://github.com/web-push-libs/webpush-java) code.  I run into a problem attempting to build the project using gradle.  (I'm a gradle newbie).

> :signArchives FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:    Execution failed for task ':signArchives'.
>     Cannot perform signing task ':signArchives' because it has no
>     configured signatory

I guess that I need to configure a signatory.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 12):

Quoting the [Signing plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html#sec:signatory_credentials) you should be able to resolve the error when you provide the expected GPG variables in the *gradle.properties* file in your *HOME* directory:

```groovy
# File location: ~/.gradle/gradle.properties - see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html
signing.keyId=24875D73
signing.password=secret
signing.secretKeyRingFile=/Users/me/.gnupg/secring.gpg
```

Gradle resp. the Signing plugin will automatically pick them up in the build process.

Answer (score 4):

Another option that does not require a special command-line option is to add the following in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
signing {
    setRequired {
        // signing is only required if the artifacts are to be published
        gradle.taskGraph.allTasks.any { it.equals( PublishToMavenRepository) }
    }
    ....
```

See e.g. https://github.com/Vampire/command-framework/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/net/kautler/publishing.gradle.kts#L157

Or Groovy (`build.gradle`):

```
signing {
    required {
        // signing is only required if the artifacts are to be published
        gradle.taskGraph.hasTask("publishToMavenRepository")
    }
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and it was because of several things:
**I didn't distribute the gpg key to any server;

I was using inMemory to sign and I shouldn't**

the link of the complete answer with build.gradle file and gradle.properties file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68505768/7937498

Answer (score -4):

Found solution here https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-java/issues/202
Use the below command.

> ./gradlew assemble -x signArchives

Comment: `-x signArchives` means don't execute the signing. While this solves the error, it doesn't achieve what the OP asked (how do I configure a signatory).