# Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven'

Tags: gradle, maven-publish

I am trying to upload a library to mavencentral for the first time. I get to build and run some tasks from maven-publish gradle plugin. But, On publish task, I get below error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenJavaPublicationToMavenRepository'.
> Failed to publish publication 'mavenJava' to repository 'maven'
   > Could not write to resource 'https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/dev/spiti/utilities/data-reader/1.0.0/data-reader-1.0.0.jar'.
      > Read timed out
```

Also, I tried the solution from here [Gradle build configured signatory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273023/gradle-build-configured-signatory) to complete :signArchives. Cmd `./gradlew assemble -x signArchives` runs successfully but issue seem to persist.

Can someone guide me thru how to overcome this.

Comment: I have the same issue. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: Same problem. Sent sonatype a message, waiting to hear back.

Comment: This could be related to error `Read timed out`. I had similar issue but failed on `jar wasn't produced by this build` which was fixed by updating [`configurations`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:configurations(groovy.lang.Closure)). This blog has solution https://newbedev.com/bootjar-mavenjar-artifact-wasn-t-produced-by-this-build